# How to echo a letter multiple times, changing more then one variable in it for each new print?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

*Hello all! This is my first question in stackoverflow so I hope I follow the rules good enough. :)*

For my PHP class I have an exercise that makes it difficult for me: Text with about 4 variables in it, all are stored in arrays (one array for each variable, 3 values for each variable).
Position [0] of each array goes in the first echo text, position [1] of each array goes in the second text and so on.
**How to echo the text 3 times using all values stored in the array? In the code I must use the main text only 1 time.**

```
$u_name = array('student' => 'Joe','lecturer' => 'Kate', 'assistant' => 'Martin');
$course_name = array('PHP', 'CSS', 'HTML');
$role = array('student', 'lecturer', 'assistant');

echo "Hi," . $u_name['student'] . "! You've been approved to take part in course " . $course_name[0] . " as a " . $role[0] . ". The course " .  $course_name[0] . " will last for two days.";
echo "<br>";
echo "Hi," . $u_name['lecturer'] . "! You've been approved to take part in course " . $course_name[1] . " as a " . $role[1] . ". The course " .  $course_name[1] . " will last for two days.";
echo "<br>";    
echo "Hi," . $u_name['assistant'] . "! You've been approved to take part in course " . $course_name[2] . " as a " . $role[2] . ". The course " .  $course_name[2] . " will last for two days.";
```

This is what I did by myself, but as you see in the code I have 3 times the main text.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Are the input arrays given in this exact format, or is that something you came up with yourself?

Comment: you need to use a loop, start from 0 and increase up to 2

Comment: you would need to use a loop, read up on [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: the only important condition is that the main text in the code must be written one time but the result use to be 3 messages with changed variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you go trough arrays with some type of a loop.

To name a few **types of loops**:

1. [for](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.for.php)
2. [while](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.while.php)
3. [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

In this case the perfect fit is a foreach loop.

It simply goes through each element of the array, but because you have a [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp) and two [indexed array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_indexed.asp) you also need a counter.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($u_name as $key=>$value){
    echo "Hi, " . $value . "! You've been approved to take part in course " . $course_name[$counter] . " as a " . $role[$counter] . ". The course " .  $course_name[$counter] . " will last for two days.";
    echo "<br>";
    $counter++;
}
```

If still are any questions left, don't mind to ask.